# Make config file available to js file in public folder in express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an express app with the following folder structure

```
app
│        
│
└───config
│   │   config.js
│           
│   
└───public
│   │   
│   └───javascripts
│       │   exportable.js
│
```

The `exportable.js` is a .js file that renders and displays a table in the frontend of the app.
I have a request to add another information to the table which includes a link to a filesystem of ours. Depending on the environment the app is running in (e.g. prod or dev) the ip address of the link changes accordingly as it does with all the other systems that the app is connected to.

All the system information is stored in the `config.js` file which for the other files outside of the `public` folder I can normally import via `require(./config)`.

Unfortunately, this way doesn't work for the files which are inside the public folder.
If I try importing the `config.js` file the same way, I receive an `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` error.

In other threads if came across the suggestion of import the file something through the likes of `<script src="config.js"></script>`. However, this is not working neither. Trying this, I receive the error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

Is there any other solutions making the information located in the `config.js` file available to the `exportable.js` file?

Comment: Since the config file is outside of the static assets folder, your frontend can't access it that way. You can create a GET route to expose the data in config.js and then fetch it from the backend from within exportable.js via the new end point. Or if you use templating (like ejs) you can pass the data in config.js as object to the template and then read the data via JS

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a file on your server directly, you must make the directory static:

```
app.use(express.static('config'));
```

This lets you access any file inside the config directory directly, for example, if you are serving on localhost, port 3000:

```
localhost:3000/config.js
```

will point to your config file.

Comment: Would this be a good way to do from a security standpoint? Say, there are other information in the config file that I don't like to be accessible via the frontend at all?

Comment: Of course. The point is if you want your client scripts to have access to a resource, it has to be publicly accessible, whether it is an asset, or a JavaScript module. If you can't allow that, because some info is sensitive, you have to use some kind of communication layer between client and server, which is you ask for a specific resource vie REST API, or Web Sockets, or any other communication protocol, and the server retrieves the right info to send for you... But since you said you were trying to do `require(./config)` , it looked like you were trying to import everything from `config.js`.

Comment: Actually, I only need a tiny bit of the `config.js` file. But since `require()` is the only way in NodeJS that I know of, yet, I mentioned `require()`.

Is it maybe possible to have like an extra folder and file created that can be made static and in turn offers a function that is accessible in `public` and returns only the information that I need?

Comment: No, that's not possible. Why not making a REST API call or a web socket call ?